# How to compute $\operatorname{Ker}(\phi )$ and $(\phi )(25)$ for $(\phi ):Z\rightarrow Z_{7}$ such that $\phi(1)=4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I understand I must find some element that map to identity but what condition  $\phi(1)=4$ is related ? and how to compute $(\phi )(25)$? I must find mapping from 25 to $Z_{7}$ isn't it ? is that 4 ?

Comment: I have some question what   $\phi(1)=4$  mean in problem ? Does it mean only 1 map to 4 or have more property?

Comment: It is  very probably a $\mathbf Z$-module homomorphism.

Comment: @Bernard Can you explain more ?

Comment: This means that $\phi(25)=\phi(25\cdot 1)=25\phi(1)$. As to $\operatorname{Ker}\phi$, it is the set of $n\in\mathbf Z$ such that $\phi(n)=n\phi(1)=0$.

Comment: Does it mean $25\phi (1)=25\times 4$ then in $Z_{7}$ $\phi(25)=2$?